# BrowserRouter not redirecting to basename (react-router-dom@5.1.2)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom@5.1.2
The project is created with a basic Create React App.

I have the below code in my index.js

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/login">
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

When I launch my development server, it still points to `localhost:3000`. Ideally, it should point to `localhost:3000/login`.

Answer (score 2):

[`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) doesn't redirect, it just informs the router that there is a piece of the URL before the part of the URL that your router will read and modify.

In your routes, just add a [`Redirect`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) at the bottom so if none of your other routes match, it will take you to the login page. Assuming you don't have a `/` route, this will accomplish what you need.

Comment: I have a `/` route as well. But I need my application to start as `localhost:3000/login`. Also, if I add `<Redirect to="/login" />`, it redirects to `/login/login` which is expected.

Comment: That makes things tricky, because you're telling react router that both `/` and `/login` are valid paths, but when you enter `/` you expect to get the other route. It's still possible though. I'm assuming you only want to send them to `/login` if they are not already logged in?

Comment: Yes. Kind of. Actually, I just started with developing my project. So, I was checking just the basic only as of now. I haven't included any logic for logged out users. So, `/` and `/login` are giving the same view when I have marked basename as `/login` and route as `/`. Ideally, the view mapped to `/` should render only when the path is `/login` if I am right.

Comment: Also, I am getting the warning as `You are attempting to use a basename on a page whose URL path does not begin with the basename.`

Comment: You really shouldn't have the `basename` set at all in this case. The warning is correct. I should have included that in my answer.

Comment: I have a requirement for the application to load only if the URL is `/login`. I thought this is the optimal solution for the same.

Comment: By adding the `basename` you're saying that every route in your app will include `/login` at the beginning. So if you have a products route, react router would set the URL to `/login/products`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202274/discussion-between-nikhil-goyal-and-brian-thompson).

Answer (score 1):

If your development server is using a different entry point than production (e.g. NX's `bootstrap.tsx`) then you can use below code to automatically bump developers to the correct entry point. Note that this is purely for DX purposes and I wouldn't recommend a JavaScript redirect like this for any production scenario.

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/login">
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
)

if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
  window.location.replace("/login")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `homePage: '/login'` in package.json to load this route by default.

Comment: won't help to redirect to /login when you navigate to localhost:3000